# How to debug failed transactions with PayPal Express Checkout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

We're using PayPal Express Checkout (implemented in Ruby, Active Merchant gem)

A few transactions failed recently, while majority work fine.

I have looked at our log file and identified the user who had failed transactions.

I have the transaction token, PayerID, user's email address, correlation ID.

I have contacted PayPal technical support about this and provided them with the above details.

But I wonder if it's possible to get more information about these failed transactions myself.
Does the Ruby gem Active Merchant provide an easy way to get it from PayPal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only information you really get back, is just basically what comes back in the API response.  Sometimes this is enough to determine what the cause of the issue is, other times it requires a little bit more looking into and [PayPal MTS](http://www.paypal.com/mts) would need to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do here to harden the Express Checkout implementation:

**Monitoring Error Code Responses**

Express Checkout will send back a series of error codes on failed transactions.  What you can do is monitor these specific error responses and that will give you an idea of what the problem with the transaction is, and in doing so you'll be able to respond accordingly (such as trying to transaction again).  Here are the error code responses for Express Checkout: http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_APIReference/Appx-ErrorCodes_and_Messages.html#2270815

**Looking up Transaction Data**

Besides the error codes, you can also use a GetTransactionDetails API operation to grab information about some transaction that might have had a problem.  This will return some useful information that would help you to handle these cases as well.  This information is available here: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/gettransactiondetails-api-operation-nvp

Hope that helps,

Jon